# python help me with this function

Tags: python, function

I need a function that Asks the user for a Stock Symbol and Name pairing then adds it to the Names dictionary. but all I have so far is

```
def addname(x,y):
    dicname = {(x): (y)}
    return dicname;
stocksymbol = (input("what is the symbol of your stock"))
stockname = (input("what is the name of your stock"))
addname(stocksymbol, stockname)
dnames = {dicname}
```

thank you anyone who trys to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def addname(x,y):
    dicname = {(x): (y)}
    return dicname

stocksymbol = (raw_input("what is the symbol of your stock: "))
stockname = (raw_input("what is the name of your stock: "))
dnames = addname(stocksymbol, stockname)
print dnames
```

**Output**

```
what is the symbol of your stock: abc
what is the name of your stock: xyz
{'abc': 'xyz'}
```

Comment: @clutchcocobean Please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? Difficult to know from your question:

```
dictname = {}

def addname(x,y):
    global dictname
    dictname[x] = y

stocksymbol = input("what is the symbol of your stock: ")
stockname = input("what is the name of your stock: ")

addname(stocksymbol, stockname)

print(dictname)
```

Prints:

```
what is the symbol of your stock: some symbol
what is the name of your stock: some name
{'some symbol': 'some name'}
```